# Call to undefined function mysqli_init() while running CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have old projects all running on PHP 7.1.1, all application are on CodeIgniter 3.1.11. I have installed new XAMPP which has PHP version 7.4.3. If I run my application on 7.4.3, I got this error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\hospital\billing.hospital\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135
```

Even if I change PHP version 7.4 on live server, the same error comes but it is running without error on 7.3 PHP version. What needs to change in my CodeIgniter application, so that I can run on 7.4 PHP version too.

Comment: It's not CodeIgniter which needs to be changed. It sounds like the PHP installation doesn't have the mysqli driver enabled. You can find out more [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=xampp+enable+mysqli) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Call+to+undefined+function+mysqli_init). What have you researched / tried so far yourself?

Comment: Did you mean that the latest version of PHP 7.4 does not have mysqli driver or what? My all application which in CodeIgniter 3.1.11, does not run on PHP version 7.4.3 but they all run on 7.1.1, 7.2.5, 7.3.1 versions. I want to run my all application on latest version of PHP.

Comment: No that's not what it means. It just means that it isn't installed (or maybe just isn't enabled) in _your_ installation. PHP is not a single big blob of code, it's actually made up of lots of different modules which can be enabled and disabled. Look at the links I provided you, and you should be able to find the solution you need. Did you spend any time doing that? I gave them for a reason.

Comment: @ADyson It's true. It's not CodeIgniter. It's the module of PHP not installed.